What is Donald Trump's crime? Why is it wrong to pay somebody money for confidentiality?
I read that the money paid by Cohen to Daniels is (allegedly) illegal. But what is illegal about it? Cohen used some housing line of credit he had.
Why can't Cohen say, "Well, I helped my friend out. And my friend returned the money sometime later"?
P.S. I am not a lawyer at all. But I can't find an easily understandable answer to this.

It's not illegal to pay money for confidentiality, it is illegal to hide the fact that you paid  money for confidentiality in the upfront of a general election by declaring it an unrelated business expense. This has really been widely discussed, even if people still refer to this as a "hush money trial".

Excessively simplified, the key elements alleged were: (a) falsifying business records to obscure the repayment from Trump to Cohen (b) for an illegal purpose (e.g. undeclared campaign financing or tax fraud)

Here is a breakdown of the charges that might be helpful: https://youtu.be/-0S9Vf64Z2s?t=43.

Mr. Trump's convictions are not based on any alleged illegality of Mr. Cohen's payments.
As explained by Lawfare, this was about falsifying business records, with the aim to hide another crime.

Trump was charged with (and now convicted of)
New York Penal Law § 175.10 in the first degree. This makes it an offence to falsify a business record with "intent to commit another crime and aid and conceal the commission thereof."
Each charge relates to "a business record allegedly falsified in service of covering up Trump’s link to the hush money payment provided to Stormy Daniels."
And each time one of those business records was falsified, it was done with the "conscious aim and objective to commit another crime."
The theories the judge allowed to be advanced for what that "another crime" could be are: (1) "violations of federal campaign finance law under the Federal Election Campaign Act (FECA); (2) violations of New York Election Law § 17-152; (3) violations of federal, local, and state tax law."

By the time of the jury instructions, the prosecution's theory had coalesced around the "another crime" being a violation of New York Election Law § 17-152. This prohibits "conspir[ing] to promote or prevent the election of any person to a public office by unlawful means." The prosecution's theory was that the unlawful means was either: (1) FECA violations; (2) violations of tax laws; or (3) other falsification of business records.
This is clear from the jury instructions at pages 27 and onward.

You also ask:

Why can't Cohen say, "Well, I helped my friend out. And my friend returned the money sometime later"?

I don't know why Mr. Cohen couldn't say that, or even if he couldn't say that. His testimony under oath was that he was directed to make the payments, and that Mr. Weisselberg explained to Mr. Cohen in front of Mr. Trump that Mr. Cohen would be paid back in 12 instalments of $35,000.

Perhaps Mr. Cohen said that because that is what happened, and he did not want to lie under oath.

@PeteB. Of course, the defense's argument was that he has no such compunction, since he has previously been convicted of perjury. That's why the prosecution had numerous other witnesses that corroborated it.

Does that mean falsifying a business record only to  save a bit of taxes is a lesser offence, or does it mean falsifying a business record with no good reason whatsoever why you are doing it is lesser offence?

Mr. Trump and Mrs. Daniels are quite free to have a sexual relationship in the USA (there are some exceptions based on someone in power more or less forcing another person).
Mr. Trump and Mrs. Daniels are quite free to tell anyone what happened (maybe not to a group of four year olds). They are free to get an offer to get paid for writing a book, and then the other person is allowed to give them money from out of their own private pocket not to write or publish that book.
But that money must come out of your own pocket. It must be money that you paid income tax for. It must not be money supposed to support an election campaign. So having a company that you own pay it, put it in the books as "lawyer costs" and getting a tax break, that is tax evasion. And spending election contributions, that's something else again.

In what sense would it lead to a "tax break"? I guess it depends on the actual source of the money, but if, e.g. it was his own private money, wouldn't it effectively lead to the company paying more taxes since the company "made" more money which it then "spent" on "legal costs"? Do we know for sure what the source of the money was?

Donald Trump could have received a salary or dividends, paid his taxes, and then paid $100,000 out of his private, honestly earned money. Instead he claimed that a business he owned had $100,000 in lawyers cost, which would reduce the profit of the business by $100,000 and lead to less taxation, plus he himself would have not paid any taxes on his cinema. If it was his money, how can a company declare it as "lawyers cost"? It's literally none of their business.

It's a complicated problem. Here's the shortest rundown I can provide
Trump and Stormy Daniels allegedly had sex in 2006
There's nothing illegal here. Trumps denies it happened.
In 2016, Daniels tried to sell her story
After the Access Hollywood tape happened, Daniels approached the National Enquirer (a US tabloid magazine) about selling her story. They, along with Trump, sought to kill this scandalous story by placing her under a legal agreement called a Non-Disclosure Agreement (NDA).
Trump hired Michael Cohen to facilitate his payment. Cohen took out a home equity loan, washed the payment through a Delaware shell corporation, and then paid Daniels that way. Trump wrote 34 separate checks to Cohen in 2017, and classified all of them as legal expenses.
Michael Cohen's plea deal
Cohen was facing charges from Federal prosecutors for tax evasion on some $4M in income. Cohen wanted a plea deal, so SDNY prosecutors had Cohen also plead guilty to campaign finance violations

[Federal prosecutors] announced today the guilty plea of MICHAEL COHEN to charges of tax evasion, making false statements to a federally-insured bank, and campaign finance violations.  The plea was entered followed the filing of an eight-count criminal information, which alleged that COHEN concealed more than $4 million in personal income from the IRS, made false statements to a federally-insured financial institution in connection with a $500,000 home equity loan, and, in 2016, caused $280,000 in payments to be made to silence two women who otherwise planned to speak publicly about their alleged affairs with a presidential candidate, thereby intending to influence the 2016 presidential election.

Later, AMI would also admit they paid Daniels to keep her story out of the media before the election

The Office also announced today that it has previously reached a non-prosecution agreement with AMI, in connection with AMI’s role in making the above-described $150,000 payment before the 2016 presidential election.  As a part of the agreement, AMI admitted that it made the $150,000 payment in concert with a candidate’s presidential campaign, and in order to ensure that the woman did not publicize damaging allegations about the candidate before the 2016 presidential election.  AMI further admitted that its principal purpose in making the payment was to suppress the woman’s story so as to prevent it from influencing the election.

Of note is that Donald Trump himself has faced no Federal charges over this.
New York law
As mentioned by Jen, mis-classifying payments is a violation of NY State law. The problem is that is merely a misdemeanor (usually charged with other crimes), and the statute of limitations is only two years.

In addition, the two year statute of limitations on the misdeamenor (New York law, CPL § 30.10(2)(a)) expired long ago, and the District Attorney did not charge Trump with the misdemeanor.  It is not clear whether the felony can stand when the misdemeanor is time barred.  The felony statute requires showing that the misdemeanor was committed, since the felony is really a penalty enhancement on the misdemeanor.

New York City prosecutors convinced a NY judge that

This was actually a felony in furtherance of covering up a crime
The statute of limitations did not apply because of the time Donald Trump was president

The base argument here is that the second crime is the Federal elections crime, to which Cohen plead guilty. The prosecutor said so in opening statements

"This was a planned, coordinated, long-running conspiracy to influence the 2016 election, to help Donald Trump get elected through illegal expenditures to silence people who had something bad to say about his behavior," prosecutor Matthew Colangelo said. "It was election fraud, pure and simple."

Cohen testified about what he did, and the jury was told of Cohen's guilty plea.
